# What are the advantages of coding based cryptosytems over LWE (Regev)?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, lwe, coding-theory

Having recently learned of coding based cryptography, it seems that they key size for post-quantum security might be a lot larger than what is required by Regev PKE (in the former keys include several large matrices), which is also post-quantum secure. Is this a correct observation? Ether way - what are the pros and cons of these two methods?

Comment: TL;DR codes:  Public keys for code-based are large (McEliece is huge, key generation takes a long while).  Some other code schemes use more structured codes to reduce key size.  Encryption is fast and ciphertexts are small.  Try looking at Appendix D of https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/nistir/8413/final for some numerical comparisons.